# Verifying optimality of heuristic solutions

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, heuristics, metaheuristics

Suppose that we have an mixed-integer linear optimization problem and we obtain a solution using a heuristic. How can one check 1) whether this solution is optimal and 2) how difficult is it to do so?

My question is motivated by an instance of CVRP. I have seen many different metaheuristics that all converge to the same solution on [this instance](http://vrp.galgos.inf.puc-rio.br/index.php/en/plotted-instances?data=ORTEC-n242-k12), so I'm wondering if we can verify whether the solution is optimal or not.

One naive way I can think of is to warm-start the MILP with the found solution, but I'm particularly interested in more advanced strategies.

Comment: For the particular case of CVRP, the state-of-the-art exact solver is VRPSolver https://vrpsolver.math.u-bordeaux.fr/ you can try to provide it the best known solution and solve the instance with it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, the only way to prove that a given solution is optimal is to obtain a valid lower bound (assuming minimization) that matches the incumbent solution (with $\epsilon$ tolerance, to be specified by the user).

To my knowledge, the only way to achieve such a lower bound is by using a branch-and-bound based solver (Gurobi, CPLEX, SCIP, Xpress, MOSEK etc.). Since you already have a (very) good solution, I would increase the intensity of the cutting plane generation (in Gurobi, this is controlled by the [Cuts](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/cuts.html) parameter) in order to focus more on the generation of hopefully effective cuts. In Gurobi, you can also set the [MIPFocus](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/mipfocus.html) parameter to 2, which tells Gurobi to focus on the lower bound.

> I think the other solvers have similar parameters, but I am not familiar with them as I work for Gurobi.

Comment: In addition to this, I would be tempted to switch the solver to depth-first search, since we are tentatively assuming that the starting solution is optimal and thus the primal bound is unlikely to improve.